# Regex Add Condition Must Have 1 or More A-Z a-z

Tags: .net, regex

Existing Regex

```
rWord = new Regex(@"\b(?:[-_'@\p{L}\p{N}]{2,40})\b");
```

Want to add the condition that is has at least one A-Z or a-z

Right now

123 would pass
abc could pass
1ab would pass

I want 123 NOT to pass as it does not have at least one A-Z or a-z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a [lookahead condition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that demands at least one letter:

```
(?=[-_'@\p{L}\p{N}]*[a-zA-Z])
```

Combined with your original, this becomes:

```
\b(?:(?=[-_'@\p{L}\p{N}]*[a-zA-Z])[-_'@\p{L}\p{N}]{2,40})\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex for one or more letter:

```
[A-Za-z]+
```

Comment: But that would not pick up ab2d.